Stability estimate for elliptic reaction-diffusion problem with inhomogeneous Neumann boundary conditions?
I want a stability estimate for the problem $$-\Delta u + u = f \text{ on } \Omega,$$
$$\nabla u \cdot n = g \text{ on } \partial \Omega,$$ where $g \in L^2(\partial \Omega)$.
The problem has variational form:
Find $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ such that
$$\int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla \varphi dx - \int_{\partial \Omega} (\nabla u \cdot n) \varphi ds + \int_\Omega u \varphi dx = \int_\Omega f \varphi dx$$
for all $\varphi \in H^1(\Omega)$.
Choosing $\varphi = u$, applying the boundary condition, and using Holder's inequality, one easily obtains
$$\|u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|g\|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)} \|u\|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)} $$
But now, I am stuck. I want to divide through by $\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ as this is what I have done for other cases (e.g. inhomogeneous Dirichlet conditions), but the boundary integral on the RHS prevents me from doing so. I am sure there is an extremely easy and standard trick for dealing with this, and I am just not seeing it. Can anyone help?
EDIT Based on the comment of user daw, I make the following update:
$$\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \leq \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|g\|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)} \|u\|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}$$
where previously I had dropped the $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2$ term, but it will turn out to be important. Applying the trace theorem
$$\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \leq \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + C \|g\|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)} \|u\|^{1/2}_{L^2(\Omega)} \|u\|^{1/2}_{H^1(\Omega)}.$$
Applying Young's inequality
$$\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \leq \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + C \|g\|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)} (\frac{1}{2\epsilon} \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}).$$
Choosing $\varepsilon = 1$ (because why not??), applying that the LHS is the square of the $H^1$ norm, and the fact that a function's $H^1$ norm bounds its $L^2$ norm
$$\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 \leq \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)} + C \|g\|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)} (\frac{1}{2} \|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)} + \frac{1}{2} \|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}).$$
And so
$$\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + C \|g\|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)},$$
or
$$\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + C \|g\|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}.$$

On the  lhs the term $|\nabla u|_{L^2}^2$ is missing. Use trace theorem, and the basic inequality $ab \le \frac1{2\epsilon} a^2 + \frac\epsilon2 b^2$.

You are a genius. Thank you so much. I have edited my post to use your hint. I hope it is right. Out of curiosity, if you have a moment: What if I had started with a Poisson problem with mixed inhomogeneous Dirichlet / Neumann conditions? Then I would arrive at a similar inequality with the boundary term, introducing an $H^1$ norm on the RHS after applying the trace theorem, but without the $H^1$ norm on the LHS to cancel things out. How would one proceed in that case?
